# Dynamic array resizing and nesting conditions

Tags: vba

This function filters a 2D VBA array base on the `strKeeper` value. Depending on the Boolean toggle it would either retain or skip "rows."

Two questions:

1. I went at length to size the `arr_new` in a separate loop to `reDim` it only once (did not want to put `ReDim` inside the loop). Is there a better way?
2. Is there a more efficient way to nest the following:

   ```
   If (arr_col_k(i, 1) = strKeeper And re_Tain) Or (arr_col_k(i, 1) <> strKeeper And Not re_Tain) Then
   ```

```
Function RemoveRows2D(arr As Variant, k As Long, strKeeper As String, headers As Boolean, Optional re_Tain As Boolean = True) As Variant
'removes rows not equal (re_Tain=False) or equal (re_Tain=True) to strKeeper in col k

Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long, up_new As Long
Dim arr_col_k, arr_new

arr_col_k = Application.Index(arr, 0, k) 'col with strings
up_new = 0 'calc Ubound(arr_new) based on matched
For i = LBound(arr_col_k) To UBound(arr_col_k)
    If (arr_col_k(i, 1) = strKeeper And re_Tain) Or (arr_col_k(i, 1) <> strKeeper And Not re_Tain) Then
        up_new = up_new + 1
    End If
Next
If headers Then up_new = up_new + 1
ReDim arr_new(LBound(arr) To up_new, LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2))

i = LBound(arr)
ii = i
If headers Then 'handle header row
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
          arr_new(i, j) = arr(i, j)
    Next
    i = 1 + 1
    up_new = up_new + 1
End If

For i = i To UBound(arr) 'outter loop by rows to find match

    If (arr_col_k(i, 1) = strKeeper And re_Tain) Or (arr_col_k(i, 1) <> strKeeper And Not re_Tain) Then
       ii = ii + 1
       For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) 'inner loop by columns to fill in arr_new row
           arr_new(ii, j) = arr(i, j)
       Next
    End If
Next
RemoveRows2D = Application.Transpose(arr_new)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the Array, counting the matches to avoid resizing the return Array is very efficient.

`Application.Transpose` is not needed because the return array is in the same shape as the original array.

> RemoveRows2D = Application.Transpose(arr_new)

This is correct:

> RemoveRows2D = arr_new

Using `Application.Index` to slice off the target column is a cool trick but is it really needed?  Not only does it add extra overhead but it adds an extra variable.  In my opinion, `arr_col_k` is just extra clutter because I don't think that  `arr_col_k(i, 1) = strKeeper` is any more readable than `arr(i, x) = strKeeper`.

> arr_col_k = Application.Index(arr, 0, k)

You can remove `up_new = up_new + 1` from this loop:

```
If Headers Then                                   'handle header row
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr_new(i, j) = arr(i, j)
    Next
    i = 1 + 1
    up_new = up_new + 1
End If
```

Moving forward, the main thing that I think you should focus on is the names of your variables.  Consider `arr, k, strKeeper, up_new, arr_col_k, arr_new`, what do the names of these variable tell you about the roles that they play?

Compare them to my alternative names.

- arr: Data, DataArray, arrData, arrSource, Source, SourceArray
- k: col, ColumnIndex
- strKeeper:  Match

  - I use Match because it is used in many VBA and Excel functions.
- up_new: Count
- arr_col_k: Matches, arrTarget, ???I would have to think about this one.
- arr_new:  Results, results, arrResults

I also use 1 or 2 character variable names for all my counters.  I prefer `x, x1, y, y1` because  `i` or `l` can be tough to differentiate.

`RemoveRows2D` is basically a 2D version of the built in `VBA.Filter` function.  Whenever I write a version of a standardized method I start by copying the methods signature from the Object Browser and work from there.  Using the same structure and variable names as the built-in methods will make it easier for others to understand and use yours.

Question: Is there a more efficient way to nest the following:

```
If (arr_col_k(i, 1) = strKeeper And re_Tain) Or (arr_col_k(i, 1) <> strKeeper And Not re_Tain) Then
```

Technically, using `If` and `EsleIf` blocks is more efficient because the VBA evaluates all the conditions in an `If Then` statement.  In your case the difference in efficiency is negligible.  Note: In my version of function I use a flag with `If` and `EsleIf` blocks because I think that it read better and is easier to debug.

```
If (arr_col_k(i, 1) = strKeeper And re_Tain) Then

ElseIf (arr_col_k(i, 1) <> strKeeper And Not re_Tain) Then

End If
```

[image: Object Browser Filter Function Image]

```
Function Filter2D(SourceArray, Match As String, ColumnIndex As Long, Headers As Boolean, Optional Include As Boolean = True, Optional Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Variant()
    Dim count As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim Results() As Variant
    'Adjust the ColumnIndex based on SourceArray Lbound
    'This allows the user to refer to the 1st column of a Option Base 0 array as 1 instead of 0
    ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex - LBound(SourceArray, 2) + 1
    'First loop to count matches
    For x = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray)
        If x = LBound(SourceArray) And Headers Then
            count = count + 1
        ElseIf Include Then
            If StrComp(SourceArray(x, ColumnIndex), Match, Compare) = 0 Then count = count + 1
        Else
            If StrComp(SourceArray(x, ColumnIndex), Match, Compare) <> 0 Then count = count + 1
        End If
    Next

    If count = 0 Then Exit Function

    'Adjust the count based on SourceArray Lbound
    count = count - LBound(SourceArray) + 1
    'Size the Results array to fit the data
    ReDim Results(LBound(SourceArray) To count, LBound(SourceArray, 2) To UBound(SourceArray, 2))
    'Reset count for reuse
    count = LBound(SourceArray)
    'Second loop to transfer the data
    For x = LBound(SourceArray) To UBound(SourceArray)
        If x = LBound(SourceArray) And Headers Then
            flag = True
        ElseIf Include Then
            If StrComp(SourceArray(x, ColumnIndex), Match, Compare) = 0 Then flag = True
        Else
            If StrComp(SourceArray(x, ColumnIndex), Match, Compare) <> 0 Then flag = True
        End If

        If flag Then
            For y = LBound(SourceArray, 2) To UBound(SourceArray, 2)
                Results(count, y) = SourceArray(x, y)
            Next
            count = count + 1
        End If
        flag = False
    Next

    Filter2D = Results
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks much, i will be sure to incorporate your suggestions.  A very interesting if not unusual comment on variable names as almost every reference suggest avoiding common names such as Match not to interfere with reserved keywords.  I guess it does not matter within function's local scope.   Re: `VBA.Filter` method on 1D array, while it's fast and powerful, it does not provide an exact match (but a wildcard like) so need to be careful as i got burned before.

Comment: I did forget that `VBA.Filter` uses an Instr comparison.  I used it in my answer to  [Is it possible to use auto-filter or find on a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162841/is-it-possible-to-use-auto-filter-or-find-on-a-dictionary) which I thought was cool.

Comment: `Match` is not a built in VBA function it is an Excel  WorksheetFunction

Comment: Your comment inspired me to do a quick hack of my code giving add an option for an exact match.  [Filter2D](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DUMIkY27JsSkJlzHqOrRMTBByUa3IrAe).  It is definitely not pretty needs refactoring.  Just something to think about when you rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

using Thomas's suggestions here is a very similar function but this employs `VBA.Filter` for membership test.  It filters 2D array by an array containing column names:

```
Function FilterColumns2D(arrIn As Variant, strArrMatch() As String, Optional Include As Boolean = False) As Variant
'removes columns either not equal (Include=False) or equal (Include=True) to strArrMatch in top row
Dim i As Long, j As Long, cnt As Long, testMatch As Long
Dim Flag As Boolean, arrOut

'loop to count matches for sizing arrOut columns
For j = LBound(arrIn, 2) To UBound(arrIn, 2)
   If UBound(Filter(strArrMatch, arrIn(1, j), , vbTextCompare)) <> -1 Then
         cnt = cnt + 1
   End If
Next
If cnt = 0 Then Exit Function
If Not Include Then cnt = UBound(arrIn, 2) - LBound(arrIn, 2) + 1 - cnt

'size the arrOut
ReDim arrOut(LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn), LBound(arrIn, 2) To cnt)

'Reset cnt for reuse
cnt = LBound(arrIn, 2)

'Second loop to populate arrOut (all rows, some columns)
For j = LBound(arrIn, 2) To UBound(arrIn, 2) 'outer loop by columns
    testMatch = UBound(Filter(strArrMatch, arrIn(1, j), , vbTextCompare))
    If Include Then
        If testMatch <> -1 Then Flag = True
    Else
       If testMatch = -1 Then Flag = True
    End If

    If Flag Then
        For i = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn) 'inner loop by rows
            arrOut(i, cnt) = arrIn(i, j)
        Next
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
    Flag = False
Next

FilterColumns2D = arrOut
End Function
```